# How to stream a video using RTSP via UDP if my computer is behind NAT?

Tags: ffmpeg, udp, rtsp, rtp

I want to stream a video using RTSP via UDP. But I can't do it because my computer is behind NAT. The stream starts normally, but after about 10 seconds it closes the stream.

I've found why it happens. RTSP uses RTCP in order to control and check if streamer is still available. It sends some "reports" to a client and the client have to send a report back to the server that it is still alive. But the message from the server can't arrive to the client because RTCP usually work via UDP and due to NAT it can't arrive, because local UDP ports sent via RTSP to the server doesn't match ports mapped using NAT.

Of course, I can use TCP instead of UDP, it solves the problem, but streaming via TCP may be much slower. I want to use UDP if it's possible for me.

I've found out that Discord also sends and receives RTP packets, but via UDP, even when my computer is behind NAT. How it is possible? I use `ffmpeg` utility for streaming, how can I do it as well and use UDP?

Hope for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There is actually an Internet draft which addresses this exact top: https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-avt-app-rtp-keepalive-10.html

They list several approaches along with their recommendation for the preferred approach.